# How to detect a moving object in a short sequence of images using opencv?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, object-detection

I am having a short sequence of grayscale images ( 20 images ), which is consecutive frames collected from a camera. I need to identify the location of a small moving object in each image. I have tried to use background subtraction, and can identify the moving pixels in each image. How can I proceed to detect the exact location of that moving object ?

Comment: Please take the time to read to see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, We cannot help you if you do not provide any code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this way.

(1) find the object using template matching at first time.

https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html?highlight=template%20matching

(2) Tracking the object using camshift or other tracking algorithm.
https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/python/camshift.py